# How can I create a `begin date` and `end date` based on the current `begin date` and the next one (if exists)

Tags: sql-server, date, t-sql

I have a table with this format

| From | To | Begin_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | A | 1220201 |
| C | A | 1220301 |
| B | A | 1220102 |
| A | B | 1220201 |
| C | B | 1220301 |
| A | B | 1220101 |

The date format is formatted like this : `1yymmdd`

What I want is for each `From` and `To` couple (per example `A`/`B`) create a `Begin_Date` and `End_Date` (based on the next `Begin_Date`) with the Format `dd.mm.yy`.

I already have the `Begin_date` since its the value given by the user. Now, for the `End_Date`, I have to check if there's a `Begin_date` bigger than my from/to couple.

Per exemple, for the `A`/`B` :

| From | To | Begin_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 01.02.2022 |
| A | B | 01.01.2022 |

It should gave me something like this (the result that I want at the end with all the from/to couple) :

| From | To | Begin_Date | End_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 01.02.2022 | null |
| A | B | 01.01.2022 | 31.01.2022 |

The value `End_date` is `31.01.2022` because there's a bigger value for this couple (`01.02.2022`) and it's a day before this value.

And if there's no bigger `Begin_date`, I just want to write `null`.

Can you help me to do this ? I couldn't find a viable solution for this use case.

Comment: what datatype is the Begin_Date column ?

Comment: what if there are more than 2 rows from A to B ?

Comment: It's a `varchar` and it should be a `date` at the end. If there's more than 2 rows, then it should be `31.12.2021` for the previous `End_date` etc (same as the current). @GuidoG

Comment: How do yo get `Begin_Date` of `01.01.2022` for `A/B` or should it  be `02.01.2022` ?

Comment: it's given by an user. So every month it changes.. it can the first day of the month, the second one, etc. @Squirrel

Comment: I was referring to the `Begin_Date` in the second table. in the first table it was `1220102`

Comment: Oh sorry, it's a mistake from me. You can only use the second table. The first table was to show how the date is initially formatted.

Comment: More than 20 years after Y2K - NO ONE should be storing two digit years.

Comment: The value "1" is for the century! the next one (2122) will be : 2220101. In my new table I stored with 4 digits years. I'm doing an ETL processus. @SMor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`lead()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or [`lag()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to get the next / previous value and then `dateadd()` to subtract one day from it.

Conversion of your dateformat `1YYMMDD` to `date` is done in the `CROSS APPLY`

```
select *,
       EndDate = dateadd(day, -1, lead(b.BeginDate) over (partition by t.[From], t.[To]
                                                            order by b.BeginDate) )
from   tbl t
       cross apply
       (
           select BeginDate = convert(date, '20' + right(t.[Begin_Date], 6))
       ) b
order by t.[From], t.[To], b.[BeginDate]
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ef80f2e56bba7d5914cb2eeafe8f0dfb)

Answer (score 2):

**You should consider storing dates in a Date Column, not in a varchar column.**

Maybe this is what you are after ?

```
select t.[From],
       t.[To],
       convert(date, right(t.Begin_Date, 6)) as BeginDate,
       t2.BeginDate as EndDate
from   table1 t
  outer apply ( select top 1
                       dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, right(t1.Begin_Date, 6))) as BeginDate
                from   table1 t1
                where  t1.[From] = t.[From]
                and    t1.[To] = t.[To]
                and    convert(date, right(t1.Begin_Date, 6)) > convert(date, right(t.Begin_Date, 6))
                order by convert(date, right(t1.Begin_Date, 6)) 
              ) t2
```

[Click on this link to see it in DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2cb1b725a859f1e4dfd215e6c70968b7)

If this is not exact what you want, then please try to explain in more detail

| From | To | BeginDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B | A | 2022-02-01 |  |
| C | A | 2022-03-01 |  |
| B | A | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-31 |
| A | B | 2022-02-01 |  |
| C | B | 2022-03-01 |  |
| A | B | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-31 |